# the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel on shared hosting server C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

We are not able to connect to https server using `webrequest` or `htmlagilitypack` It showing below error

`The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.System.Net.WebException:` or `could not create SSL/TLS secure channel on server`

Our code works fine on localhost and we also added following portion in my code file but we aren't able to identify why it's happening only on the server.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

if anyone has any idea on this then please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is because the webrequest wont accept self signed certificates. I have this singleton class I usually use. It accepts all self signed certificates. It would be easier to determine if there is a simpler solution if if you shared the url you are trying to access.

```
public sealed class Certificates
{
    private static Certificates instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Certificates()
    {
    }

    public static Certificates Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Certificates();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
    public void GetCertificatesAutomatically()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors)
                => { return true; });
    }

    private static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        //Return true if the server certificate is ok
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        bool acceptCertificate = true;
        string msg = "The server could not be validated for the following reason(s):\r\n";

        //The server did not present a certificate
        if ((sslPolicyErrors &
            SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)
        {
            msg = msg + "\r\n    -The server did not present a certificate.\r\n";
            acceptCertificate = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //The certificate does not match the server name
            if ((sslPolicyErrors &
                SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
            {
                msg = msg + "\r\n    -The certificate name does not match the authenticated name.\r\n";
                acceptCertificate = false;
            }

            //There is some other problem with the certificate
            if ((sslPolicyErrors &
                SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
            {
                foreach (X509ChainStatus item in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if (item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown &&
                        item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.OfflineRevocation)
                        break;

                    if (item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                    {
                        msg = msg + "\r\n    -" + item.StatusInformation;
                        acceptCertificate = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //If Validation failed, present message box
        if (acceptCertificate == false)
        {
            msg = msg + "\r\nDo you wish to override the security check?";
            //          if (MessageBox.Show(msg, "Security Alert: Server could not be validated",
            //                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
            acceptCertificate = true;
        }

        return acceptCertificate;
    }

}
```

Just call the method before doing a web request like so.

```
Certificates.Instance.GetCertificatesAutomatically();
```

Also it would help diagnose the problem if we could see(the code) how you're making your webrequest.